# Non mutually exclusive case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I write this query so that these segments are not mutually exclusive? It seems that once a record is found in the ‘DMA’ bucket, it gets excluded from finding it in the other files.  And I need to see when the records are found in all the files.

```
SELECT LastName
    ,Address1
    ,Address2
    ,City
    ,Zip
    ,DealerRegion
    ,SuppressionReason
    ,max(CASE 
            WHEN [File] = 'DMA'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS InDMAFile
    ,max(CASE 
            WHEN [File] = 'VEH'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS InVEHFile
    ,max(CASE 
            WHEN [File] = 'LST'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS InLSTFile
    ,max(CASE 
            WHEN [File] = 'V12'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS InV12File
    ,max(CASE 
            WHEN emailaddress IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS HasEmail
    ,max(CASE 
            WHEN Emailable = 'Y'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS CanEmail
FROM mytable
WHERE SuppressionReason IS NULL
GROUP BY LastName
    ,Address1
    ,Address2
    ,City
    ,Zip
    ,DealerRegion
    ,SuppressionReason
```

Comment: You have independent statements.  Someone can appear in all of them.

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff - The code you're written ***already*** is  non-mutually-exclusive *(a record can be in both DMA and HasEmail, for example)*.  I would advise you to create a dummy set of data and add it to your question, so that you can demonstrate empirically what ***does*** happen and then describe what you ***want*** to happen.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve